# R, list all packages and versions used in a markdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown

Hi  I'm using R and R studio.  Is there a way I can have my R markdown file list all the packages and their respected versions at the end of the documents? thanks!  For example,

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

## R Markdown

```{r cars}
library(ggplot2)
library(gplots)
summary(cars)
```
````

Comment: `sessionInfo()` or `session_info()` from `devtools`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the names of loaded non-base packages with `names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs)`, so maybe something like this:

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

## R Markdown

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
summary(cars)
``` 

```{r}
installed.packages()[names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs), "Version"]
```
````

[image]

Comment: This fails to list the package name if only one package is loaded. Also, `installed.packages` can be slow. I've written a short function [package_versions](https://gist.github.com/cbrnr/86d70e3d3398f0a9f5a33b1f4ba03a2a) which solves these issues.

Comment: Of course you could also use `sessioninfo::package_info`, which includes much more information. If you only want the versions of the attached packages, use `subset(data.frame(sessioninfo::package_info()), attached==TRUE, c(package, loadedversion))`.